# Can I create a Custom Error Statement instead of auto generate error statement in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, error-handling, azure-data-factory

[SYSTEM GENERATED ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z41PF.png)

in the image, you can see there is a system generated error after failing a pipeline. But, I want a custom error( altered/ edited message by a user for any failure )that will pop up in place of system generated error after running a pipeline.

Comment: No, we can't. Data Factory doesn't support custom the error message for now.

Comment: While others are correct in the sense that ADF itself does not support custom error messages I see from your example that you are using Stored Procedure Activity and launch Databricks Notebook Activity. For both of those there are some additional options if you are okey with moving this functionality to those resources. Can you please specify where your main code is located, and what functionality do you seek to achieve with it? Can you please share some of the notebook code as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Error message cannot be changed.